# Assembly - extract specific bit

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I want to extract 17th bit from my 32bit (int) value. Am I doing this right? I'm using AT&T syntax.

```
movl $0x11112222,%eax   
movb $0b01000000,%bl
andb %ah,%bl
```

I put 32bit number into 32 bit register. Now 17th bit is in ah register (as well as other 16-23 bits). Now as it is second bit in ah register, I created a "mask". Then I'm doing and operation.
Am I thinking right about this?

Comment: Sure you are. But the thing is `%ah` will be changed. Thus, if you want the value won't be changed you should use `test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea could work, but you have the wrong constant and the wrong byte. Your mask should be `0b000000100000000000000000` (or more readably `0x20000`) and you should use 32 bit masking because you can not access the byte with bits 16-23. You mistakenly stated those live in `%ah`, but that's wrong, as `%ah` has bits 8-15.

Also, this operation will leave the bit in place. Depending on what exactly you want you can shift the whole eax right by 17 and then keep the least significant bit.

Comment: Generally I have to write script, where I take 17th bit from few numbers, then XOR them etc. Is this and operation proper in that case?

Comment: With the fixed constant, yes, if you always need bit #17. Note you can xor your numbers first and then extract the result once.

Comment: Wait a minute, I didn't spot your mistake ... `%ah` does **not** have bits 16-23, it has bits 8-15!

Comment: Ah, yeah. So it should be al then?

Comment: No, al is bits 0-7. You can not directly access the top two bytes. You will need to use a 32 bit masking against the full eax.

Comment: Shifting the register 18 bits to the right will put the 17th bit into the carry flag from where you can BCC/BCS depending on whether it's set or not. Much faster/smaller than anding it with 4 bytes in memory. (And, yes, I know that destroys the original value but *that's what registers are for*!